# Is there a way using to insert unescaped HTML in Ionic, something like {!! !!} in Laravel?

Tags: ionic-framework

In Laravel, there're '{{}}' and '{!! !!}' can be used, but now I want to develop my app with Ionic. And my target is to let one user type some text with 'line break', and the other one can see the text the first one user typed.

Here's the situation I face:

User A type "TESTING (enter to change line) TESTING"

But User B see "TESTING
TESTING"

But I expect User B to see "TESTING (enter to change line) TESTING"

In Laravel, that's easy to solve this, but how can I do this in Ionic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this one is not ionic related but rather angular related.
In Angular 2+ you would do it the following way

```
<div [innerHTML]="yourHtmlString"></div>
```

And if your 'yourHtmlString' variable contains html line breaks they will now be rendered.

here is a plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/z4aeGsKnUaBk1zW6v9by?p=preview

Note: If your input comes from a textarea input you probably need to convert \n to

Comment: Thanks! This is the one!!